How to Restrict Manual Date Input to Valid Years in MUI DatePicker?
I'm using the MUI DatePicker component in my React application and facing an issue where manually entered dates with incomplete years, such as 0202, are being interpreted as valid dates (0202-01-01). I want to restrict the input so that only dates with valid four-digit years are accepted.
Here's the code I have so far:

import React, { useState } from "react";
import { DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker";
import dayjs from "dayjs";

const ValidityCellRenderer = ({ params, handleDateChange }) =\> {
const \[validUntilTime, setValidUntilTime\] = useState(
params.data.validUntilTime ? dayjs(params.data.validUntilTime) : null,
);

    const handleValidityDateChange = (newValue) => {
        if (dayjs(newValue).isValid()) {
            const isoDate = newValue ? dayjs(newValue).toISOString() : null;
            setValidUntilTime(newValue);
            handleDateChange(params.data.subscriptionId, isoDate);
        }
    };
    
    return (
        <div
            className="datediv"
        >
            <DatePicker
                className="subsdatepicker"
                disablePast
                value={validUntilTime}
                onChange={(value) => handleValidityDateChange(value)}
                format="DD/MM/YYYY"
                openTo="day"
                views={["day", "month", "year"]}
                mask="__/__/____"
                PopoverProps={{
                    anchorOrigin: {
                        vertical: "bottom",
                        horizontal: "left",
                    },
                    transformOrigin: {
                        vertical: "top",
                        horizontal: "left",
                    },
                }}
            />
        </div>
    );

};

export default ValidityCellRenderer;`

Problem: The DatePicker allows entering years manually like 0202 and it looses focus, which is treated as the year 202.I want to ensure only valid four-digit years are accepted.
Desired Behavior:Restrict manual input to only allow dates with valid four-digit years.
How can I modify the above code to ensure that manually entered dates must have valid four-digit years?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
